# Coin flipping problem

Tags: probability, problem-solving, conditional-expectation

Suppose that you are flipping a coin endless times. what's the expected round where you would get the same side $3$ consecutive times? I'm guessing it would take $7$ flips to see either `HHH` or `TTT` sequence. Because the expected flip to see a `HH` or `TT` is $6$ flips and plus the initial flip it would $7$.

Am I correct?

Comment: I don't think you are right about the expected number of flips to see a HH or TT, btw.

Comment: Ah, the problem is the use of the word "or". The number of tosses expected to get HH is 6. The number of tosses expect to get TT is 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach.  Let $t_k$ be the expected number of tosses needed to see $k$ identical flips in a row.  Clearly $t_1 = 1$; the first toss is always identical to itself.

We can create a recursion as follows.  In order to get $k+1$ identical tosses in a row, we must first get $k$ identical tosses, which takes time $t_k$.  On the next toss, with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, we achieve our goal of $k+1$ identical tosses; but also with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, we are back to the square one (we can use the toss that set us back as the first toss of the new attempt).  Thus

$$
t_{k+1} = t_k + \frac{1}{2} \times 1 + \frac{1}{2} \times t_{k+1}
$$

which can be simplified to obtain

$$
t_{k+1} = 2t_k+1
$$

This recurrence is easily solved with the boundary condition $t_1 = 1$ to yield

$$
t_k = 2^k-1
$$

and in particular, $t_3 = 2^3-1 = 7$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\psi(i, j)$ be the expected number of rounds to reach state $j$ from state $i$, where $i,j = \{0,1,2,3\}$.

$\psi(0,3) = 1+ \psi(1,3)$

$\psi(1,3) = 1+ \frac{1}{2}\psi(1,3)+\frac{1}{2}\psi(2,3)$

$\psi(2,3) = 1+\frac{1}{2}\psi(1,3)+\frac{1}{2}\psi(3,3)$

$\psi(3,3) = 0 $

Solve for $\psi(0,3)$. The answer is $7$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x_n$ be the probability that, after $n$ tosses, you still haven't gotten three in a row, and you currently have $1$ in a row - that is, you are are on your first toss or the previous two tosses were different. Let $y_n$ be the probability that you haven't yet gotten three in a row and you currently have the last two equal. Let $z_n$ be the odds that you've gotten three in a row at some point in the first $n$ tosses.

We are seeking: $$\begin{align}\sum_{n} n(z_n-z_{n-1}) &=\sum_{n}\sum_{j=1}^n (z_n-z_{n-1}) \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{n=j}^{\infty} (z_n-z_{n-1})\\
& = \sum_{j=1}^\infty  (1-z_{j-1}) \\
&= 1+\sum_{j=1}^\infty  (x_j+y_j)\end{align}$$

**Markov Chain Approach**

You see that:

$$\begin{pmatrix}x_{n+1}\\y_{n+1}\\z_{n+1}\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&0\\
\frac{1}{2}&0&0\\
0&\frac{1}{2}&1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_{n}\\y_{n}\\z_{n}\end{pmatrix}$$

The expected time to get three in a row is:

$$1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty  (x_n+y_n) = 1+(1,1,0)\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A^{n-1}\right)(1,0,0)^T$$

Where $A$ is the above matrix.

The eigenvalues of $A$ are $1,\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{4}$. So $x_n+y_n = a+b\left(\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{4}\right)^{n-1} + c\left(\frac{1-\sqrt 5}{4}\right)^{n-1}$ for some values $a,b,c$.

You know that $x_n+y_n\to 0$, so you know $a=0$.

We know that $x_1+y_1=1,x_2+y_2=1$.

So solve for $b,c$.

Then $$1+\sum_n (x_n+y_n) =1+\frac{b}{1-\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}4} + \frac{c}{1-\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{4}} = 1+b(3+\sqrt{5}) + c(3-\sqrt{5})$$

The final step is to solve for $b,c$.

I'll skip the work, and tell you that $b=\frac{5+3\sqrt{5}}{10}$ and $c=\frac{5-3\sqrt{5}}{10}$.

Plugging this in, and we see the expected value is $7$.

---

** Generating function approach **

A similar approach, using generating functions, with less algebra, is to see that $y_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}x_n$, and $x_{n+2}=\frac{1}{2}(x_{n+1}+y_{n+1})=\frac{1}{2}x_{n+1}+\frac{1}{4}x_n$.

So you have a linear recurrence for $x_n$.

Then $$\begin{align}f(z)&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x_{n+1}z^n \\
&= 1+\frac{1}{2}z + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2}x_{n+2} +\frac{1}{4}x_{n+1}\right)z^{n+2}\\
&= 1+\frac{1}{2}z + \frac{1}{2}z(f(z)-1) + \frac{1}{4}z^2f(z)\end{align}$$

So we see that $$f(z)=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}z-\frac{1}{4}z^2}$$ and $f(1)=4$. But then, since $y_1=0$ and $y_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}x_n$, we have $\sum y_n=\frac{1}{2}\sum x_n = 2$.

So $\sum (x_n+y_n)=6$ and the expected value is $7$.

**Generalized:**

For $k+1$ tosses in a row, let $x_{n,i}$ be the probability after $n$ tosses you have not seen $k+1$ identical results in a row, and you currently have seen $j$ identical tosses in a row. Then again, you have the expected value is:

$$1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{k} x_{n,k}$$

You also have that $x_{n+j-1,j} = \frac{1}{2^{j-1}} x_{n,1}$ and $x_{n+1,1} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_j x_{n,j}$.

Altogether, this means that $x_{n+k,1}=\sum_{j=1}^{k} \frac{1}{2^j}x_{n+k-j,1}$.

Letting $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x_{n+1,1}z^n$, we can show that:

$$f(z)(1-\frac{1}{2}z-\frac{1}{4}z^2-\cdots-\frac{1}{2^k}z^{k}) = 1$$

This is because the first $k+1$ coefficients of $f(z)$ coincide with the first $k+1$ coefficients of $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-z} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{2-z}{1-z}$ and the first $k+1$ coefficients of $2\frac{1-z}{2-z} =2-\frac{2}{2-z}$ coincides with $1-\frac{1}{2}z-\dots-\frac{1}{2^k}z^k $ so the first $k+1$ terms of the product is $1$, and the higher terms are zero by the recurrence.

So $f(1)=\sum x_{n,1} = 2^k$, and the expected value is then $2^{k+1}-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Denote by $E_k$ $(0\leq k\leq 2)$ the expected number of additional throws when you have $k$ equal throws on the top of your stack. Then
$$E_0=1+E_1,\qquad  E_1=1+{1\over2} E_2+{1\over2} E_1,\qquad   E_2=1+{1\over2} 0+{1\over2} E_1\ ,$$
with the solution $E_0={\bf 7}$, $E_1=6$, $E_2=4$. That's it.